# Create an LLVMModule from a single, existing function

Tags: llvm

I'm using the c API of LLVM to create libFoo.a, which should contain a single, trivial (x+42) function, to be called from my main programm.
I am able to create Foo.o and from there libFoo.a, however it ends up containing a few other functions which I don't want to be part of it, since they cause linking errors (e.g. due to multiple main functions).

Logically, I would expect two ways to solve this: Either by removing not needed functions, or by creating a new LLVMModule which just contains the function I need.

I'm creating Foo.o by calling `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(target_machine, ModuleWithTooManyFunctions, "Foo.o", LLVMCodeGenFileType::LLVMObjectFile, error_msg)`

I have my desired function available by an LLVMValueRef.
I'm quite new to LLVM, so I don't know how to proceed from here.
My first solution (creating a new LLVMModule, calling LLVMAddFunction on it) got stuck when I noticed that it expects a TypeRef instead of a ValueRef.
Since I'm generally not too convinced about my attempt to solve this I thought I might ask here.

Comment: LLVM contains [utility functions to clone a function into a module](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Cloning_8h_source.html), but AIUI that's outside the scope of the C wrappers.

Comment: So clarify, you want to create a separate Foo.o which only contains the (x + 42) function, whatever that one is named?

You may also want to use `LLVMObjectFile` over `LLVMCodeGenFileType::LLVMObjectFile` as that's what the C API exposes, but that's up to you.